# Ideas on how to set a button to call a specific position from an ArrayList in a separate activity

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, parcelable

*Long post ahead...*

Ok, I'm not sure how to explain it so I made a couple of screenshots. Also, I want to start off by saying **I'm not looking for somebody to write code for me to copy**, or links to specific articles. I just need help figuring out if what I want to make is possible and any direction on what to look at. I just haven't done something like that and so far I can't seem to word my searches well enough it seems to be able to find a solution.

[image]

***TL;DR: I need to get scrn2 to either swipe left and right to prev/next card from the RecyclerView, or add buttons that do that***

So. Here's the screenshot. I have already made scrn1 and scrn2, and am looking for a way to get to my mockup (*that heart button there is just wishful thinking and I'm not at all concentrating on it, and the buttons on top of the cards are just a left-over from an old test I forgot to remove*).

The idea behind this is just sort of a catalogue/text book to help with self-preparation for an exam on a specific topic.

**What I have** is a RecyclerView that I've populated with CardViews in an ArrayList. Since I'll be having a few cathegories of cards, and each will have around 40-50 in there, this seems like an efficient and quick way to load a long list like that, and it runs smoothly so far so I'm happy with it.

In order to get a "full details" screen (scrn 2) **I implemented Parcelable to my single item template/class**, and now when I click on a card I get that second activity that shows the full sized image, title and full description text.

I also added a search that filters the cards in real time, since there will be many of them and I want it to be easy to get to a specific item.

So far so good. Everything works, surprisingly.

**Where I'm stuck now** is that it will be extremely annoying for somebody to keep going in and out of the single items in order to get to the next one, so I need to be able to **either make them scroll or have buttons at the bottom that go to previous and next**. The thing is, the only time I've used swiping is in a tabbed activity and that requires fragments. When making those I had to have an xml for each tab, and a class to correspond to it, which is definitely not comfortable when I have 40 in 10 categories.

I assume I need something like an onClick event to add for buttons in the activity that holds the information that gets acquired from the RecyclerView to bring a specific position from my ArrayList... Like, if somebody clicks on the third card, the button brings -1 or +1. *Or something like that?*

Makes some sense in my head, but I can't find a way to search for that, and can't figure out if it's even possible to make. Soo any pointers would be hella useful. I'm really excited about being able to do that much from scratch, but still lack too much knowledge to be able to imagine what would work here. I'm still testing things out and am looking around for information, but will be happy if somebody has input on the situation.

Comment: Are you using fragments or activities?

Comment: The simplest way imho is to use Fragments with a PagerAdapter which provides the swipe gesture. You can provide different Fragment classes or layouts with it or just create the layout in .getInstance(something). To get the same effect with Activities with buttons and a swipe gesture recognizer seems more complicated.

Comment: Both screens on the shots are activities

Comment: Just wanted to get back and say thanks to @Christian, really pointed me in a direction to work with and I've sketched out a route to go. Thank you!